# error: relation "vinyls" does not exist, but works in psql

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, express

I am trying to add/get row to my table and I am getting the error:

> error: relation "vinylstable" does not exist

`vinyls` is my db name and `vinylstable` is my table name,

When I type in bash: `psql -d vinyls -f vinylstable` I can see the table with 1 row inside.

[image: vinylstable]

my vinylstable.sql looks like this:

[image: SQL TABLE vinylstable.sql]

My db.js (just for get) looks like this:

[image: db.js for getvinyls list table]

and my index.js looks like this:

[image: GET route]

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you share your JavaScript code that sets up your database connection?

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: If it works in `psql` but not in your application, then in 99% of the cases, you are connecting to a different database (or with a different user) from within your application.

Comment: That was the case... I was trying to connect to a different database.. thank you guys.